# Why was earth created and why did we come to Earth?

Tags: gods, earth, creation

Why did our supreme lord create Earth and why did we come to Earth? From where did all this  start?

Comment: The purpose of creation is not canonized in Hinduism unlike in other religions. There are many interpretations and views in each philosophical system.

Answer (score 16):

### Earth is stage, we all are actors

Earth is like **a stage** where we all see drama movie. We all are actors and we are performing our roles.

We are the eyes, mouth and hands of existence. If the self does not interfere, the nature sees,,speaks and acts through us.

> **Life is considered as Yajna for others.** We are given body to do some work as per our skills and knowledge.

There is always a life but most of them are for the existence of self but actually it is given to make it meaningful by helping others.

> A meaningful life isn't about acquiring money and other facilities; it’s about dedicating your life to helping others as much as you can.

We are not of this body and this body is not of ours. This body is made of materials of this planet so is mortal. The invisible energy that is called Aatman is **Ansh**(Purush) of `Parmeshwara` that controls the body.

You can consider a driver who is driving a car. Car is body but it is not driver. `Aatman` is the actual driver. When car crushes someone we do not say car killed , but we say driver killed.

> Earth is nothing but just a planet "a stage" where all the drama take place. We are souls who play the roles in this drama with various culture, various nature , various beings.

The earth is created to provide all materials that one needs to be alive, to create, to farm , to survie, to kill to do anything with the material.

What we do depends on us. But what we need is provided by earth.

When we know that we want our child to study well, we provide all facilities like pencil, eraser to him/her. Thus God provided all the toys to us that we need to do something.

To enhance our skills, to be civilized he provided society. Otherwise why wouldn't he make a new planet per soul??

There is no land where God did not provide standard living life example.

There is no soul with loneliness.

Choice is always of child's to make life meaningful. But the requirements are always satisfied.

Whatever happens is for good and whatever will happen will also be for good.

Trust your inner values and play the role because the role given to you is only you can play the best.

You can’t help someone just by making a wish to do so, you have to take action. That's why we came here. to take action.

> "You are wonderfully made."

Look at the world around you, the infinite detail and creativity. Unimaginable beauty surrounds us every day. You are part of that creation, materializing from the same artist that created sunsets and rainbows. Don't ever allow yourself to think you are anything less than wonderful.

> Creativity is good for the soul.

Creativity is when your spirit gets a chance to play and express itself. So whether art, dance, cooking, making music, writing, or creating a garden, let yourself go! Create!

> Whatever fills your heart with gladness is a good thing.

Let yourself be filled. There is much joy and beauty in the world if you only open yourself to it.

> "you" matter.No one else can be the person you were created to be.

People need you. People you love and even people you have never met are depending on you. You matter to God as well. Do not think for a minute that you are not important; - the world needs you.

You are for earth and earth is for you.

> you are being asked to be a steward of this earth.

God entrusted this earth to us. Not to trash and spoil her, but to respect and treat her well. After all, this earth is the handiwork of God.

*The answer was finished here only*

---

**EDIT : ** (For the comment of `Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta`)

### The ultimate Truth of Geeta and concept of stage and actors

In [Gita](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-09-33.html) Lord mentioned Earth as "म्रुत्यु लोक" and told Arjuna to do "कर्म" work with the memory of "GOD" and "भजस्व माम्" means "Worship me".

By doing so "You will reach me."

Another time Lord Krishna mentioned

> "Soul is eternal But soul's rising or fall is only possible when **soul is in body**. By doing "कर्म" work"

"Without body soul has no feelings."

I just explained this by writing "Playing a role"

**Why I wrote it?**

On stage some drama is going on. My name is parth but now I am going on stage and playing a role of "SID".

Now may be my role is of 20 minutes. For these 20 minutes I will say dialoges of SID and act as SID only. Everybody identify me as SID. But in reality I am Parth!!

And I used "acting" -> "Doing "कर्म" work"

> Actually my "कर्म" work is not binding me with fruit (Either good or bad) but my wishes, faith or my greed behind doing that work is binding me.

So if you know that "Parth" is just a notice board to identify me on earth (Obviously on my license, passport it is written) But in reality I am **soul** sent on stage(earth) to play this role(Parth or SID).

And if you seriously consider your self and all others as soul only, you will do all your "कर्म" work with no sin , no wish , no greed but with pure heart and that will not bind you and by doing so you will be freed without "कर्म" work you did.

One more thing is having the memory of GOD in mind,too.

> Why worshiping GOD?

Because drama is always made by some "DIRECTOR", "STORY Writer".. Isn't it??

The actor never says his own dialogue. There is some director or story writer who has created/written this show.

> If in drama my scene is to fight with another actor, but if I do it like "This is just the director's order", will I have any bad feeling or hurt feeling with another one??

But if it is so, **what about the creativity of an actor**?? Can't he has his own acting skill, dancing skill, his own dialogues and all that??

Yes, GOD knows that. So he creates situations. But the real decision is your own "कर्म" work.

> Your every decision taken may bring you either closer or away from GOD. The more you remember god more exams he will take of yours.

I wrote `"when Soul is in body"` Because by body itself soul can express or do creativity. And also if soul has done bad then punishment is also possible only in body. (BECAUSE I DO NOT BELIEVE IN HELL OR PARADISE). If some one has killed many and died, how can people on earth know that he got punished in hell or not?

NOBODY KNOWS and nobody can know.

**Why Punishment?**

To stop others by doing sins. Otherwise nobody will care of what they do. Is the earth for sins or "Moksha"?

**When Punishment?**

When GOD realize that this soul is making poorer itself by continuously making sins only and this soul's rising is only possible with new body then and only GOD punish with death. That's why Lord asked Arjuna "to kill" in Mahabharata war.

So this drama is necessary. In Hindu scriptures it is mentioned that in human life someone can make powerful soul by attaining `"Moksha"` which is considered as main goal of life. But it is not possible without having a human life. That is why we come on earth. Obviously GOD is not willing for anyone to sin. But bad people may do so because of ambitions. **But we can not say that everything good is because of GOD's will**. When we are about to do some bad work like stealing some thing(football), our good sense always says that this is bad, but our mind says `"I want it, nobody is looking, just steal I do not have football, I love it , steal"`, If we control it then it is called `"योग"` and if mind controls us then that work's fruit will bind us. Mind is like a small child and brain is like a elder child. Both are given to soul as powers. **GOD is witness** of everybody's brain and decision but **never interfere.**

> In Gita Lord said I can not prevent fate of this war!!! when society lost gentleman or gentleman choose not to do work society creates war for itself. This war is result of Good people's inactivity, like King Pandu, Bhishma, Karna and Drona.

Between your fruit and you, GOD never interfere.

To be free, the concept of playing role is important to understand.

One more thing By just attaining `"Moksha"` we are given life?? If so good people will take `"Sanyaas"` (go to jungle for meditation and worship god), isn't so?

But what if someone take good water from river, what is left? Only mud.

When good people choose not to interfere(in activeness), the society is led by sinners.

> In such situation Even though I attain "Moksha" , will it benefit society?

No. This is called **selfishness**. To help others we have to sacrifice and " To sacrifice" is called "Yajna".

**Life or Sacrifice means?**

Giving time, doing karma, sharing, putting smile on someone's face, supporting someone in sadness, sometimes not doing anything but just to breath.

> Joy will come when you pass on the love you have received. do not save happiness share it on different faces.

That is why I said "Life means living for others(Yajna)"

Whatever I wrote is in Gita, read it for more details.

Do you still think `"Vishwaroopam"` is just what all gods appeared in one?

No it is we all who are on earth. This is real knowledge of `Gita`.

In Gita ,

1. Sankhya Yog -> know yourself (you are soul, Purusha)
2. Karma Yog -> Do work as actors, do not bind your self
3. Bhakti Yog -> Get properties of GOD and his help by worshiping unto him
4. Gyan Yog -> Understand the ultimate truth and rise yourself

**The ultimate truth**

> પ્રત્યેક જીવ શિવનો જ અંશ છે જે આ સત્યને જાણી લે છે તે સંપૂર્ણ સત્ય નો જાણકાર છે અને સદાય બીજાઓ સથે હળીમળીને જીવે છે.

Each soul(जीव) is the child of supreme soul(शिव), who see each soul as brothers to him, always live with compassion for others.

Also you will be interested in this one. [Birth and Death - two unavoidable moments](https://www.facebook.com/notes/parth-trivedi/birth-and-death-two-unavoidable-moments/10200883967020511)

**EDIT 2:** *(For the comment and edit of question of 1. Where did it start?2. if I would god and I am complete why would I created others?)*

When there is no universe == universe exists? (Are universe and nothing are two sides of mirror? Are these two only GOD's two images? Form ness(Prakruti) vs Formlessness(Purusha))

If I draw circle, after the circle is drawn.. how can I know the starting point? (Because according to Hindu mythology Creation,Existence, Destruction is cycle , repeating many times) This is called `Aaadi`, `Madhya` and `Aant`, how to identify egg came or bird, first?

Then what is the GOD?

> God is formless.

1. Knowledge
2. Light
3. Happiness

These 3 things are not made of Proton, Neutron and Electron.

But without Body (made of Proton, Neutron and Electron), they can not be felt.

There is a difference between "Jad" means Dead things like table,spoon,wall,land and "Living Being" like souls.

**What is the difference?**

Dead is dead, and soul has "Chetana".

**What is Chetana?**

Liveness is called chetanta. We can think ideas,creativity and all non-material things like feelings,love and all. Dead things does not have them.

In Hinduism GOD is explained as having "Chaitanya Swaroop"

Dead body is "Prakruti" nature, and living soul is "Purusha", Ansha of Parmatman.

With the combinations of these two Living being is possible.

### **GOD Nature**

If I am GOD, I am complete. I am the only one.  Nothing is there. But why to create? Why to operate and why to Destroy?

G - Generator - Genesis
O - Operator
D - Destroyer

why?? (What I believe)

> Because this is my(GOD) nature.

This is my(GOD) nature only. May be this is because of my will or may be it is my(GOD's) fate.

> in Geeta lord said that also that the universe creation is `superintended` my me only.

[see the verse here](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-09-10.html)

### **From where did it start?**

That is why in `Rug Veda` it is written

> When there was nothing everything was just "Sat swaroopam"(Combination of Prakuti and Purusha) and fire of love arose in the GOD and GOD became the universe it self. God decided to be divided himself in cycle (because loops have no end), 3 cycles (Generation, Operation, Destruction), 3 times (Morning, Noon, Evening ),3 worlds (Eartg, Heaven, Hell), 3 Guna (Properties) (Satva, Rajas, Tamas), 3 devatas (Brahma, Vishnu , Mahesh) (GOD is "Nirakar" means with no shape - But took "Sakar roop as deities"), 3 phases of life (Birth, Life, Death), 3 kinds of creatures (On Land, On sky, Under water), 3 Tattva (Proton, Neutrone, Electrone), 3 numbers (+ve,0,-ve) ... Many is written.

**Why 3?**

To cause loop 3 is important

**initialization**
 
**Operation**
**end**

And repeating this means loop.

Yes origins are always in cosmic from (like seed of tree, egg of bird and all planets,stars are circle) Because circle is presentation of infinite loop.

There is no difference between universe and GOD, both are the one.

Aadi(Beyond time)
Anant (Infinite)
Shiva (Pure and beneficer)

and GOD nature is to create,operate and destroy -> this is called "Trugunateetam"

**Role of GOD**

If I am GOD I must have 3 things

1. Pure ->  I should be supreme soul
2. Powers -> I must hold all powers of universe
3. Beneficier -> I must benefit `others`

For 3rd one I need `"Others"` (souls) who may consider me a supreme soul, but I must benefit them, then and only I am GOD. Being only pure may not benefit OTHERS, being powerful may or may not benefit others but being `beneficier` with purity makes a GOD (Shiva).

*I may edit this answer to explain more if I have some more thoughts on this one.*

Comment: Parth thanks alot for the answer :) However you didn't told me why we came on earth, what was our(so many souls) purpose to be sent on earth, since the lord himself does everything and nothing can't be done against its will. why?

Comment: My dear bro.. We came on earth to play a role in which we will do various work and bring glory to GOD. What we can do that only we are supposed to do. GOD knows what we can and will ask us to do that only on earth. The purpose of GOD is that we will bring glory by doing something good to him. If we do something good here, he will be happy. Our main purpose of life is to help others. If we make 100 people smile then it is larger than life.

Comment: For your question `since the lord himself does everything and nothing can't be done against its will. why? ` I would suggest you to ask another question in stack overflow because this question needs a long explained answer. Send me the link of it, I will answer it also.

Comment: GOD may create a situation for you. But based on your decision in that situation the next step happens. And the decision you took is your KARMA.

Comment: I don't believe that god needs glory, if don't know if you've read Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta or not.. read it and you'll get it that god is complete in himself... and after reading that i asked this question on Hinduism.

Comment: Thank you very much SID.. I have edited this answer. Actually you just read `Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta` but my name is `Parth`(Arjuna's another name called by Lord Krishna) whom Lord actually said. Yes I may not that one Arjuna, but whenever I read it I feel like Lord Krishna is saying to me. Some thoughts appear in my mind every time I read it. I just shared some of them with you,my brother. I hope my understanding of `Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta` may explain you something. Yes I may be wronge in undeerstanding too, I accept it and looking for real answer of your question, too. :)

Comment: This answer is too long and rambling.  You need to make it more organized.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan SrinivasanThe answer was very small but as SID commented about Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta, I had to edit it !! Anyways I will try to organize it.. Thank you

Comment: @ParthTrivedi : again thank you for the updated answer and its not like that i just believe in what is written and not in inner values,ethics and soul... Let me try and explain you what i'm looking for.. As said in Bhagwat Geeta, God is complete in himself then why create earth and other souls(part of parmatma), why seprate us from the supreme soul? I take reference of bhagwat geeta because that has been said by god himself... PS no hard feelings with you.. :)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi : to explain you more further try and understand this..suppose you are god and you are happy with yourself and at peace, then why would you create a stage(earth) and become a director, assign many roles, do so many things and manage them when the ultimate goal of doing so is to **attain peace and contentment** which you already had before creating a stage and actors. hope you got my point, i tried to explain my question in very simple and easy words. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two type of yoni(body)

- Karma Yoni
- Bhog Yoni..`

Human Being are Karma Yoni, rest all living being (insect, tree, animal, devta etc) are Bhog Yoni.

We humans came here to do Karma so that we will be rewarded according to our karma.

So what is the reward? The reward is (Heaven, Moksha, Bhakti and there are many other rewards)

Comment: First of all, you should cite sources.  Second of all, you shouldn't put something in block quotes unless you're quoting something.

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in the Upanishads that we were all once in God means in His kingdowm. We all existed in perfect peace, love, and harmony with the Supreme Being. But as we are all individual souls we wanted to expereince duality we wanted independence from God and thus we all came out of that union with God. Duality means opposite of everything that is present with God. We had to experience many ups and downs and through all these ups and downs to reach God again. And because the Supreme Being loves us so much that he created this phenomenal universe for us to experience duality. That is also the purpose of reincarnations.

Comment: Can you please share the source, where did you read so in upanishads?

Answer (score 1):

Creation is a subject of experience. Scriptures do give answers of how all things were created. E.G. refer Devi Bhagavatam (9th book, chapter 3) for example. But unless you have a direct experience, it'd just be an idea you've got from somewhere with no way to verify it.

So leaving creation, the better question for us is "why are we here?"
Gita gives answer. We're here because of our desires. As long as we have even a single desire related to this world, we'd have to come to fulfill it. It's not our karma that binds us, our desires do.

Sri Krishna says (paraphrasing) that only fool thinks that God does everything and we're mere puppets. God has given us free will and created us in his image. So we're free to make a choice. If our choices are guided by selfish desires, we become bound to this world.

Nature runs on a self-fulfilling prophecy, God doesn't interfere in day-to-day workings of the nature. Even God's avataras are bound to reap fruits of karma when descent on this plain (lot of examples from Sri Ram's/Sri Krishna's life).
There's no ceasing of karma as long as we're alive here. Which also means that the fruits of our karma has to be reaped by us till then. Nature has a karma bank in this city of universe and each one of us has an account in it. As long as we remain in here, we've to put deposits. We can only withdraw what we have deposited.
But if we have no desire to remain in a city, the bank can't bind us. We can thus forgo the entire deposit and be liberated.