# Did world get destroyed by god?

Tags: vedas, gods

Does the world gets destroyed by gods? many people said that when the gods become angry on people they destroy the whole world with the help of water,fire etc.
example:flood,tsunami etc.

why this all Done? it is one of the **Global warming** are the **Anger of our God**?
Many educated people said it is a effort of deforestation and global warming.
And some people said it is angry of God which one is true? and what vedas said?

Comment: The World or Universe runs in cyclic nature of time, Creation-Preservation- Destruction continuously. After certain time, Dharma degrades in every Yuga. At those times Lord will incarnate and He will restore Dharma. Global Warming is not anger of God. This is result of our  actions in past decades. At the end of Kalpa, earth is destroyed and after the end of Pralaya Earth is formed again. See this question [How was the universe created?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8508/3500). It's just a cycle of Creation-Preservation-Dissulution with no beginning and ending.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  It seems like this question would lead to too much opinion-based speculation, so I'm closing it for the time being.  If you want to edit it so that it's more of a concrete factual question about Hinduism, like "Does Hinduism say that all natural disasters are caused by the gods?" or something, then it may be more acceptable.

Comment: First of all, He is not a God if gets anger just like us. The calamities we see on earth are caused by our actions only. Regarding the destruction of the world. The word destruction is wrong here. In Hinduism we use a word called    samhara, pralaya. Which means collecting things with care to preserve them for some purpose.

Comment: In scriptures its said that Siva does this job and preserve all the jivamshas at the end of kalpa. The reason for this they is to give rest to all souls for sometime which are tired because of life-death cycles.

Comment: In almost all the hymns of Hindu gods they are described as "nirguna",  "nirahankara", " nirvikalpa", "ananda" that means they don't have ego, or any mood changes. They themselves are embodiment happyness. Swamy Vivekananda explained God as bundle of positive thoughts. Then how can they be  sometimes angry and sometimes happy?