# Do new God's emerge from Parabrahman at the end of each Mahapralaya?

Tags: vedas, puranas, history, belief

Please clarify the following:

1. If other Mahapralayas have occurred before, have the same God's always emerged from Parabrahman (such as Shiva, Shakthi, Vishnu etc) or do different God's emerge at the beginning at each Shristi(creation)? For eg. How do we know Lord Ram will appear in the next Creation and has appeared in previous ones?
2. Does Parabrahman create different God's each time a new creation begins?
3. Do our scriptures specify on the creation of God's after the Great Dissolution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the theory of creation of the universe as per agama/tantra section of Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17131/what-is-the-theory-of-creation-of-the-universe-as-per-agama-tantra-section-of-hi)

Comment: Very thorough thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Life span of Hindu gods](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23190/what-is-the-life-span-of-hindu-gods)