# How does Avyakta turn into Vyakta

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Hi my question is regarding one shloka from Bhagavad Gita.
It states that the universe has come from the unmanifest (avyakta) and manifested (vyakta) itself.
Where in the Vedas is this process explained in detail?

Comment: Good Qn. I think that process is probably undefined. It just happens as a **due course of time**. Even scientists who believe in big bang are also wondering that if the whole universe energy was concentrated in an infinitesimal point then how it blasted to eventually create further universe?

Comment: Related: [How was the universe created?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8508/277)

Comment: In the Srimad Bhagvatam First Scand (volume/canto).

Comment: This process is taken from Sāṅkhya philosophy rather than Vedas. Prakr̥ti is said to have two forms, avyakta and vyakta. Avyakta is the cause of vyakta, and it proceeds by satkāryavāda. So, if you want to study this process, classical Sāṅkhya should be your go-to.

Comment: @Bingming thank you for you comment. I will study Samkhya then. Do you know any good book on Samkhya?

Comment: *Classical Sāmkhya: An Interpretation of its History and Meaning* by *Gerald James Larson* is a classic introductory secondary text, it also includes the translation of Sāṅkhyakārikā  as well  in the appendix and discusses the kārikā in detail along with the mention and critique of prior scholarly studies on Sāṅkhya. So, it's a well rounded text and according to me good introduction for beginners.