# Why is only Earth (Prithvi) chosen for life of human beings?

Tags: brahma, life, earth

According to astrology (Jyotisha), there are nine planets (Graha). Brahma created many planets and among all planets, He made only earth (Prithvi) livable for humans. He established life only on earth, not on any other planet. I want to know why only the current planet is chosen for human beings? Is there any related story or reason described in scriptures?

Note that I'm not talking about [Lokas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loka#Hindu_tradition), I'm talking about planets i,e [Grahas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navagraha).

Comment: Why life is available only on Mother Earth?... This may not be true.. What u are asking is why only on earth humans live? Both are different questions..

Comment: Different beings have different lokas as their residence. Devas have Devaloka, Nagas have Nagaloka, similarly we have the Bhuloka or the earth.

Comment: @Rickross I use Human word in description of my question. So here I am talking about Mrityu loka's life or we can say Humans and Animals and Trees. May be life word is confusing.

Comment: @Rickross Besides, any non-humans lives in all other planets? Since m talking about only Planets.

Comment: Humans live on earth because its given to them as their abode..Just like u live in ur house and ur neighbour in his house similarly different beings are alloted different lokas to live on.. If we go on their lokas or if they come to our lokas there will be chaos.. Also life is there in other lokas too.. Or else do u not consider Devas, Gandharvas, Asuras etc as living beings?

Comment: @Rickross Please check updated question.

Comment: Related or duplicate of [Why was earth created and why did we come to Earth?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/why-was-earth-created-and-why-did-we-come-to-earth)

Comment: @iammilind You should read both question carefully before commenting. My question is totally different. Check update. Never comment before understanding question properly.

Comment: @Rishab, "Why planet earth is chosen" -- is a moot point, because whichever planet we stay would be termed as "earth". Currently your Qn boils down to: "Why did Brahma choose only 1 planet for living beings?" or "Why did Brahma choose 3rd planet (i.e. Earth) from the Sun for living beings?" IMO, they are either broad or off-topic. I still feel that your Qn is quite similar to the linked one. Due to lack of clarity, I mentioned "**Related** or Duplicate". Hope that clears the point.

Comment: @iammilind My question never being **boiled down**. I am asking same thing since begining of this post. Read unedited title of my question in which I am using **only** word. In first unedited paragraph I am asking why **only earth have life, why not any other planet**. I am repeating myself pls read question carefully before commenting.

Comment: I almost finished constructing answer. WIll post it in one-two days . Direct answer is hard to get. But I  am just trying.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63584/discussion-on-question-by-rishabh-why-life-is-available-only-on-the-mother-earth).

Comment: @Rishabh You can edit the question by including Sanskrit names. For example, why Brahma made only Bhuloka suitable for life? Why not Angaraka or Shukra? You can also include i want answer from hindu Scriptures. Also, mention you want to know all life or just *Manava* or Humans.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Since I am talking about Bhrama's deeds then how it relates to sceince?. You consider Brahma as Sceintist?, so that asking about his decision/choice/karma will become science speculations? Presence of Brahma alone doesn't proof that I am talking about Hindu Gods. And since this sites is totally based of English Language then Why should I used Bhuloka word instead of Planet, Since both has same meaning. This is not making any sense to me. Give me one reason of this question is related to sceince. Just coz it don't contain sanskrit words....? Really?

Comment: @Rishabh I'm not the one who said this is scientific speculation. But some users felt this question is scientific speculation. Using Sanskrit terms gives less chance to make it related to Science. Also, not everyone agree Bhuloka is earth. Some believe Bhuloka is entire milky way. Problem is with interpretation. So, i suggest you to add Sanskrit terms and statement "i want answer from Scriptures only" to make this question out of scope of "Scientific speculation".

Comment: @TheDestroyer Seems people here just likes to play with flags.

Comment: @Rishabh you will edit it?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I am planning to raise this issue on meta. How people can blindly flag any post. If they don't have sense of fagging then they don't have right to flag. I want them to realize that what they did is totally wrong. They won't realize that if I will just edit my post. They will give reason of their deed in meta. I will post in evening.

Comment: @Pandya Sorry to say but the most of the users of this site is totally senseless. First they said my question is based on science speculation. Now you add one extra word "**Astrology**" and it is not based on science any more lol. I was using Earth word instead of Prithavi and Planet word instead of Grah. Since this site is based on English language then why I can't use words Earth and Planet instead of Prithvi and Grah respectively. Will it become science speculation if I won't use Hindi or Sanskrit words in there? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Pandya And why do I need to add that I want answer based on sriptures. Ofcourse I want my answer based on Purana or vedas or any related Hindu source since I am asking on **Hinduism.stackexchange** . It is not like that I want my answer from Stephen Hawking's book of Space Science From a Hindu site. It is common sense.

Comment: @Rishabh [Jyotisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyotisha) (which includes astrology and astronomy) is one of the [Vedanga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanga).

Comment: @Pandya So without present of this single word, my question will be related to science? On what basis?

Comment: @Pandya Astrology says there are nine planets.Yes, but Earth is not among them. Your edit makes no sense. Because earth isn't a planet according to astrology. It is loka only. I wiki link you added says that. Check it. And yes, I agree with Rishabh. we need not to add "what do scriptures say?" before every question. That doesn't make an off-topic Q on-topic and vice versa. Why are we using Sanskrit words in the questions when there are English words? This is an English language site. Does the change of English-sanskrit makes the question on-topic?

Comment: See [Planets, celestial bodies and lunar nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navagraha#Planets.2C_celestial_bodies_and_lunar_nodes). Sun and moon are included as planets.