# In which year of exile did Hanuman meet Bhima?

Tags: mahabharata, hanuman

It is said that Hanuman met Bhima for the first time when the latter was going through the 13 year exile period but do scriptures tell anything about the exact year in that period when the two met?

Comment: Related or potential duplicate [What was the age of Hanuman when Bheema met him?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20129/1049)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What was the age of Hanuman when Bheema met him?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20129/what-was-the-age-of-hanuman-when-bheema-met-him)

Comment: @PratikBhat When did I ask the age of Hanuman?

Comment: @iammilind How this question is duplicate of your mentioned one? Both are totally different question.

Comment: @Rishabh, you need to check certain [unofficial] terminologies in SE sites. I discussed [here with you before](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20118/why-is-only-prithivi-current-planet-or-graha-choosen-for-life-of-human-beings?noredirect=1#comment57609_20118). When a Qn is mentioned as "Related or Duplicate", then that means that the Qn is surely **related** and if anyone of the Qn is extended a bit, then they may become duplicates. e.g. If this Qn asks "In which year of exile, did Hanumana met Bhima & how old was Hanumana", then the linked Qn can become dupe of this & vice versa.